# How to install Spyder for Python 2 and Python 3 and get Python 3 in my Spyder env?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, spyder

I have Python 2.7 installed (as default in Windows 7 64bit) and also have Python 3 installed in an environment (called Python3).

I would like to use Spyder as my IDE. I have installed Spyder3 in my Python3 environment, but when I open Spyder 3 (from within my Python 3 env), then it opens Spyder for python 2.7 and not python 3.5 as I would've hoped for.). I don't know why.

I have done `TOOLS--Preferences--Python Interpreter -- Use the following Python interpreter: C:\Users\16082834\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Python3\python.exe`, but this didn't work either.

Many of us are running multiple python environments; I am sure some of you might have managed to use Spyder for these different environments.

Please tell me how I can get Python 3 using this method.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to run `activate Python3` and then run `pip install Spyder`.

Comment: Thanks so much Pankaj Joshi ! I found the issue. In essence you are right. But if you install spyder inside your environment, and you have a python2.x and not 3.x version, then spyder will automatically link to that version of python. So be sure that your new env. actually is running the desired python version.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you create a new environment with: conda create --name python36 python=3.6 anaconda

This will create an env. called python36 and the package to be installed is anaconda (which basically contains everything you'll need for python).

Be sure that your new env. actually is running the ecorrect python version by doing the following:

activate python environmentwith: active python36

then type: python

this will indicate what python version is running in your env. It turns out, for some reason, my environment was running python2.7 and not 3.6

The cool thing is that anaconda distribution comes with spyder. Just be sure that you run Spyder from within your environment.

So to do this: activate python36
then type: spyder

It will automatically open spyder3 for python3.

My initial issue was therefore that even though i created a python3 environment, it was still running python2.7. But after removing the old python3 environment and creating a new python3 env. and installing the desired libraries/packages it now works perfect.

I have a 2.7 and 3.6 environment which can both be edited with spyder2 and spyder3 IDE